# Sequelize - Custom Operators

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I'm interested in adding a couple custom operators to our usage of the Sequelize ORM. Specifically I want to add on operators that mimic the [startswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#startswith) and [endswith](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#endswith) lookup operators that Django has implemented. Looking through the internals on Sequelize, I can't seem to find the place where it would be to inject this kind of logic. In short, the functionality I'd like to implement is something like:

```
{
    stringField: {
        [Op.startsWith]: 'bl'
    }
}
```

to produce the desired sql of

```
WHERE stringField LIKE 'bl%'
```

I know that in the documentation all the examples show manually appending the `%` symbol but for my purposes I want to be able to dynamically wrap the value based on the operator being used.

Comment: I think this would mean extending the main query generator logic of the library which might be quite difficult. What's the disadvantage of just using `Op.like`?

Comment: Well, the disadvantage is that currently, to achieve dynamic capabilities with some query param filtering, we have a mechanism that has to manually specify for certain fields the server should mutate the data value to `${value}%`. It'd be just a nice convenience to have just an `Op.startswith` that automatically did the wrapping for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the current version of sequelize,

```
Post.findAll(
  {
    where: {
      someAttribute: {
       $startsWith: 'my name' // or from the request body field value
     }
    }
  }
)
```

This can be found from the sequelize docs here for more operators. [sequelize operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html)

Otherwise you can replace the $startsWith with the old version to suit your needs,

```
[Op.startsWith] : "field value"
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available. We've worked around this by applying some middleware before the sequelize ORM that transforms a 'custom' operator into a real operator.

```
[Symbol.for('substring')]: value => ({[Sequelize.Op.like]: `%${value}%`})
```

Comment: how did you add your custom middleware?